# Asus Eee-PC 1015PEM

Tags: charging, eee-pc

My Asus  worked perfectly until yesterday. I assume that the battery drained and AC was not plugged. I turned it on and doesn't chargeat all.  It seems that something wrong with my battery. It works from AC but when it is plugged it shows only 4% available charging. When I unplug AC it shuts down right away. I already tried the 45  seconds holding power button method, and I uninstalled in device manager Microsoft ACPI-compliant Method Battery. Nothing helped. Does anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Well, it could be that the software is wrong about the available charge. I would shut the laptop down and give it some time to charge undisturbed. Your physical charging indicator will tell you when it's done.